# Multer image upload in Nodejs and Express

Tags: node.js, image, express, upload, multer

I've been trying for days to upload an image using Multer. This is how  far I got. I tried multiple things, and can't seem to make it work. I don't know how to use Multer to upload an image in my createUser function in the format shown below.

My  ' server.js ' file:

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'});
var router = require('./app/routes');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var session = require('client-sessions');
var DB_URI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/portfolio";
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+ '/public'));
app.use(session({
  cookieName: 'session',
  secret: 'random_string_goes_here',
  duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
  activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
}));

mongoose.connect(DB_URI);
app.use(router);

app.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log("server is listening on port 8080");
})
```

My  ' routes.js '

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var projectController = require('./controllers/projectController');
var userController = require('./controllers/userController');
router.post('/regUser', userController.createUser);
```

My ' index.ejs '

```
<form class="form inv" method="POST" action="/regUser" id="reg_form">
          <h3 style="margin-bottom:40px;">Register</h3>
          <!-- <input type="file" name="file"/> -->
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name"/>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
          <input type="file" name="userPhoto"/>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
```

My userController.js

```
createUser: function(req, res){
//add code to create user AND upload image
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems.

First : your form does not have the enctype attribute set. `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is required for file submission to work.

Second : you require `multer`, but you are not using it. Add this

```
app.use(multer({ dest: '/tmp/'}).single('userPhoto'))
```

(or with another method ([see documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)), like `.array()` or `.fields()`)

You could then access the file in `createUser()` like this:

```
createUser: function(req, res){
    console.log(req.file); // this displays the userPhoto's properties
    fs.readFile(req.file.path, function (err, data) {
        // do something with the file data
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to add only a single photo. So should I still add enctype="multipart/form-data" to my form tag?

Also, my main issue here is that I am new to Nodejs and Multer and all. So I don't know how to use file that is submitted by the form to createUser to upload it to my uploads folder? 

Thanks in advance

Comment: I get this error TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions

Comment: Thank you very much Lorenz :D

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been posted two months ago, but to those who is experiencing the same problem,

I think you must add enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form

```
<form action="url" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and in your router.route you must add upload.single() or upload.any()

```
router.post('/regUser', upload.single(), userController.createUser);
```